# Multi workspace shifting with multiple screen

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, xfce, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I have Xubuntu 16.04.4 LTS. I am using it with two monitors.
Second monitor is the extended view of the first monitor.
When I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd> (it's not the default setting) to shift the workspace, it switches it on both screens.
Is there a way to make the workspace switches on these two screens separate?